# How to link main.cpp, a.h and a.cpp?

Tags: c++

Forgive me if I'm doing something incredibly stupid, but I have 3 files:

main.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
//x = 0;
```

a.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

int x;

#endif // A_H
```

But it doesn't compile. I think `x` is being defined twice. What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x` is defined in two translation units (because the defining header is included by two cpp files). Define it only once:

main.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
int x = 0;
```

a.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

extern int x;

#endif // A_H
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `int x` in a.cpp and `extern int x` in a.h.